# ZP4 address parsing batch script

Tags: batch-file

How do I create a Windows script that executes the command:

```
C:\ZP4\AUTOFIXD C:\FOLDER\PARCELS.DBF \HOME\LIST.LAY SKIPFIRST UPLOW
```

for any and all PARCELS.DBF files that might be in `\FOLDER\` and all subdirectories.

I.e the script would be equivalent to:

```
C:\ZP4\AUTOFIXD \FOLDER\PARCELS.DBF \HOME\LIST.LAY SKIPFIRST UPLOW
C:\ZP4\AUTOFIXD \FOLDER\SUBFOLDER1\PARCELS.DBF \HOME\LIST.LAY SKIPFIRST UPLOW
C:\ZP4\AUTOFIXD \FOLDER\SUBFOLDER1\SUBSUBFOLDER2\PARCELS.DBF \HOME\LIST.LAY SKIPFIRST UPLOW
...etc.
```

but only for each PARCELS.DBF file that actually exists.

`\HOME\LIST.LAY SKIPFIRST UPLOW` are unchanging parameters used by `AUTOFIXD`.

Answer (score 0):

If powershell is an option, I'd recommend it.

In PS:

```
$files = gci -r C:\ | where {$_.Name -eq 'PARCELS.DBF'} 

foreach ($file in $files)
{
     C:\ZP4\AUTOFIXD $file \HOME\LIST.LAY SKIPFIRST UPLOW
}
```

untested as I don't have ZP4 on this box, but basic premise should work

Answer (score 0):

The `for` command can iterate over things. So assuming that you either have no Unicode file names or use a TrueType font for your console window:

```
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /s /b PARCELS.DBF') do C:\ZP4\AUTOFIXD "%%x" \HOME\LIST.LAY SKIPFIRST UPLOW
```

Comment: ok, so I tried to run the above script with powershell and I got this error " missing opening '(' after keyword ' for '. "

any ideas ?

Comment: It's not PowerShell. You tagged your question with `batch file` so I gave you a batch file, not a PowerShell script.

Comment: Ok, I made a BAT out of the above sciprt but it won't run. Do I have to substitute the working directory  for %%X ??

Comment: Nevermind, I got it to run now ! Thank, now I just need to add "c:\program files\ZP4\ZP4.exe" to the script so I dont have to open in manualy before running the script each time.  Can I just paste "c:\program files\ZP4\ZP4.exe" into the script, or do I have to tell it to first run the exe, then run the script ??